# useEffect sometimes gives null error, due to the changes in the "error" variable coming from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a form submitting page,
There is a useEffect hook I use for the changes in the error from Redux, So when error returns from backend and fills the reducer, It refreshes the error variable by the help of useSelector, so I can reveal error message in the DOM where I use Material UI

```
const BugForm = props => {
  const { classes } = props;
  let error = { image: "", title: "", description: "" };
  let modalState = useSelector(state => state.bug.modal);
  error = useSelector(state => state.UI.errors);

  const initialFormState = {
    category: "",
    project: "",
    priority: "",
    viewStatus: "",
    resolution: "",
    reproducibility: "",
    title: "",
    description: "",
    image: ""
  };
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ initialFormState });
  const [openErrorSnack, setOpenErrorSnack] = useState(false);

  // this is for the useEffect to just fire one time in the load:
  const firstUpdate = useRef(true); 


 useEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate .current) {
      firstUpdate .current = false;
      return;
    }
    setOpenErrorSnack(true);
    error.image = "";
  }, [error.image || ""]);

//for updating the form values:
const updateField = e => {  
    setValue({
      ...value,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

When I submit the form it gives error, sometimes this is happening when I first load the page, sometimes it does not:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null
BugForm
C:/Users/2C/Desktop/reactjs/ticketApp/client/src/components/bugForm.js:116
  113 |    }
  114 |    setOpenSnack(true);
  115 |    error.image = "";
> 116 |  }, [error.image || ""]);
      | ^  117 | 
  118 |  const updateField = e => {
  119 |    setValue({
```

And here is the post action:

```
export const postBug = newBug => dispatch => {
  console.log(newBug);
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
  checkTokenExpire();
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(newBug).forEach(key => bodyFormData.append(key, newBug[key]));
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bugs/",
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
  })
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_BUG,
        payload: res.data
      });
      dispatch(clearErrors());
      dispatch({ type: CHANGE_MODAL });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data ? err.response.data : err.response
      });
    });
};
```

and UI reducer for errors:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  errors: {  },
  modal: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: action.payload
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: null
      };
    case CHANGE_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem and is there any proper and secure way to use useEffect in this kind of situations?

Comment: Should it be `useState(initialFormState)` instead of `useState({ initialFormState })`? You are creating a nested object with `initialFormState` as key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clear errors, on reducer, you set error to null so the useSelector return null to the variable error and so the error.

I think you can choice some alternatives:

- during clear you can set errors to {} instead of null
- useEffect can have error (and not error.image) in its dependences, so inside the useEffect you have to check if error is null

Furthermore I think is unuseful to sel error with let, because useSelector overwrite it.
And as write adiga you have to set initialFormState without {}.
An other think: I think you can't do error.image = "" without using dispatch

Comment: That's the thing... I totally forgot clear_errors, each time it nulls the error... I am looking into this for 2 days and I couldn't see that. Thanks for the help (and I changed the useState also)